# How exactly do you use NPM scripts and echo while executing a command?

Tags: npm, comments

I cannot find any documentation on displaying messages in the terminal when executing NPM scripts.

For instance `"bsync": "echo 'Starting BrowserSync' browser-sync start"` does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### You can create bash script

Create any script you like (and even complex scripts)

Add the script to the your bin folder or to your /node_modules/.bin folder

And then add the following in your script section in package.json

```
 "scripts": {
    "bsync": "./bin/echo.sh"
  }
```

and create your echo.sh script:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo 'Starting BrowserSync' browser-sync start
```

### The other option is to direct echo

```
"scripts": {
    "bsync": "echo \"Starting BrowserSync\" && exit 1"
  }
```

Comment: Ah, so in regards to the direct echo I would need `&&`

Comment: This second option will echo the string with quotes and exit with an error.  However, the complete command is echoed prior to execution.  Do you know how to just perform the command?  If it's a batch command, an @ in front would work, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: echo is not platform specific

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate a bit more; you can add multiple commands to one script by using `&` and `&&`.

- `&` parallel execution
- `&&` sequential execution

So an example could be:

```
"scripts": {
    "bsync": "echo 'Starting BrowserSync' && browser-sync start"
}
```

By using double quotes and backticks in the string to be echoed, you can also use substitution, for instance something like this:

```
"scripts": {
    "bsync": "echo \"Unix timestamp: `date +%s`\" && yarn somescript"
}
```

Or  supplying a command line argument to an npm script

```
"scripts": {
    "bsync": "yarn somescript $(echo timestamp.`date +%s`)"
}
```

*(using `yarn` but it could also be `npm run`)*